# polymer: Grid Layout

Tags: css, html, polymer

I am trying create a sort of Grid Layout in an web app through polymer's layouts. 
I am using div elements with the 'wrap' attributes but (as expected) they end irregularly. I'd like them to end at the same width and create a regular shape.

here is a snippet of what I am doing (part of a Jinja2 template)

```
<div horizontal layout wrap style>
        {% for el in elements %}    
        <my-card> {{el.content}} </maker-card>
        {% endfor %}
</div>
```

the problem is that el.content is different in size for any elements ad the resulting grid appears irregular.

Comment: Please post some code.

Comment: code posted, thank you

Comment: Do you have any suggestion ?

Answer (score 0):

You just have to add

```
flex auto
```

to the polymer element